# (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:997)')))

Tags: python, api, ssl, curl, python-requests

When  run below python code in putty then it's producing output whereas the same is not working in vscode

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
print('Started..')

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

data = '{"ss":"adsd","des":"sdfs"}'

response = requests.post('https://sdfsf',
                         headers=headers, data=data, verify=False, auth=('use', 'pwd'))
#print(response.stdout.decode())
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.text)
print('Completed..')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run in PuTTY"? Presumably you're connected to some remote machine? What versions of Python are you using locally vs. on the remote machine?

Comment: I am using python 3.10.7 and in remote machine we are using Python 2.7.5

Comment: Python 2.7.5 is _ancient_, and many years out of support. It doesn't even receive security updates anymore. I strongly urge you to stop using it. At minimum, you should upgrade to 2.7.18 (the last release of Python 2), but even that is three years out of date.

Comment: In general, you can't expect Python 2 and Python 3 to behave the same. Pick one (Python 3! Ideally 3.10 or 3.11!) and use it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you but with python 3.10.7 how to call an api endpoint. I dont see it's supporting that. I do want to use 3.10.7 but would like to know if there are any libraries to work with

Comment: Can you [edit] the complete error message into your question, with full traceback, please? I suspect whatever server you're trying to hit is using an obsolete certificate.